# How to Label Every Corner of a Polygon Layer

Tags: arcgis-pro, labeling, grids-graticules, township-range-section

I have a township and range polygon layer on my map and I want the section number to be labeled in every corner (4 labels per feature). I've gotten the labels to generally place in corners by using Regular Placement type, then checking the box for "Place label at fixed position within polygon" and assigning numbers to the corners and 0 to all other slots. This works for one label per feature, but I can't figure out how to add one to every corner without doing it manually. I tried changing the minimum interval under Repeat, but the results seemed very unpredictable.

I also tried to do this using map frame grids in the layout view, but when using a "custom grid", it seems that I can't add the grid lines as a component.

I would think this would be a common thing to do but I can't seem to find any resources that address this exact issue.

Comment: Perhaps try to export your vertices as points, set their symbol to 'no colour' and use the points to label. Adding a grid may be unavailable if your data frame has no coordinate reference system defined.

Comment: You're correct... it is  a common thing to do.  My method is similar to @Michael_Stimson comment.  And because it's something I need to do more than once, I've created a tool to do it.  (In my case, I need to have the vertex points visible AND to label them with the vertex coordinates.)